# MVC - DropDown Value not Binding in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

In my View I am using a `Helper DropDown`. I am facing issue that the data is `not getting binded` to the `DropDown`. When i set value for the `ShiftId` from Controller that value should get selected in the DropDown, which is not happening in my case.

```
@{Dictionary<string, string> shifts = (Dictionary<string, string>)ViewBag.Shifts;}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].List[q].ShiftId, new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(shifts, "Key", "Value"), "Select")
```

Comment: What do you mean set the value in the controller, as in when rendering the view?  It seems like your iterating a list when creating these dropdowns how are you doing that

Comment: Yes List is populated in Controller but the `Value` which is set in the `List` is not getting defaultly selected in the `DropDown`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generating the dropdowns in a loop, and unfortunately this is a limitation of the helper. You need to generate a new `SelectList` in each iteration (which you are doing), but you also need to set the selected value in the `SelectList` constructor.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].List[q].ShiftId, 
    new SelectList(shifts, "Key", "Value", Model[i].List[q].ShiftId),
    "Select"
)
```